# Sequel add a 'scope' according to a conditional

Tags: ruby, database, sequel

The code goes like this:

```
class Foo < Sequel::Model
  self.dataset_module do
    def property_active
      where('properties @> \'{"active": true}\'')
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  def foo_ids
    Foo.select(:other_model_id).distinct.all
  end

  def condition?
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to modify the `foo_ids` method to add the scope `property_active` depending o the `condition?` method. So far I come up with this:

```
Foo.select(:other_model_id).where{ Foo.property_active if condition? }.distinct
```

And it returns:

```
# when condition? is true
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"other_model_id\" FROM \"foos\" WHERE (SELECT * FROM \"foos\" WHERE (properties @> '{\"active\": true}'))"

# when condition? is false
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"other_model_id\" FROM \"foos\""
```

The code is good, but I don't like the idea of having that `SELECT` after the `WHERE`, is there a way to return a nice query for the `true` case? something like:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT \"other_model_id\" FROM \"foos\" WHERE (properties @> '{\"active\": true}')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the way Sequel handles chaining and scopes, but this is how I would approach it with the way ActiveRecord handles this. Does this work?

```
class Bar
  def foo_ids
    scope = Foo.select(:other_model_id)
    scope = scope.property_active if condition?
    scope.distinct.all
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, hopefully there's a Sequel way to do it.

Comment: @zetacu Not sure what you're looking for that's different. The composition style I've used is also used in the [introduction to Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#an-introduction).

Comment: I was looking if there was a sort of sequel method to nest queries into one, like `Model.query.conditional_query.query` something like `Foo.where(bar: 'somethig').some_conditional_restriction_sequel_method.where(foo: 'something').all` in that way I can add it into a more functional programing, I believe the only way to do something like that will be adding an scope, but was hopping that sequel already has that build in.

Comment: @zetacu That really belongs in your app, not delegated out to an ORM.